# How can I split a string by it's datatype in java?

Tags: java, split

In my plugin for Spigot, a player enters a command such as `/logging chat clear 1d`. The argument number 2 (3rd arg) which is `1d` needs to be parsed for date (e.g. 1d = 1 day, 15m = 15 minutes). I've figured out the parsing part, but when I try to parse more than one number (1 vs 11) my parsing doesn't work because I split based on characters, not based on if its an integer or string. I do `String[] part = arg3.split("");` then take the first character as the number and second as the string. 
**How can I do this but split so that I can have multiple numbers? (regex?)**

Comment: Why not just make it `1_d` or `15_m` and just make life easy? (split on the separator)

Comment: Because this is an extensive project and I need to parse for all possible dates, so I do it by number. E.g `20w` is 20 weeks, and `210w` is 210 weeks. I can't just parse for certain steps.

Comment: I meant take your input with a separator being `_` then use `.split('_')`.  You would take it as `20_w` and the array would contain `{20, w}` after the split.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I don't want to have a specific seperator, but rather keep the argument to the smallest possible size.

Comment: Is the second argument always 1 letter or can it be larger? (the `w` or `d`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void myMethod() {
    String integers = "";
    String characters = "";
    String splitArgument = ""; //this is the 1d or 11d part
    for(int x = 0; x < splitArgument.length(); x++) {
        Char currentChar = splitArgument.charAt(x);
        if(Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
            integers += currentChar;
        }else {
            characters += currentChar;
        }
    }
}
```

Where myMethod just represents the area of the code you are analyzing the input in. You can create a method (as isInteger()) that takes the characters from the String you are checking and determines whether they are Integers/String and re-concatenate Strings for them. For the integer part you could then do:

```
int myInteger = Integer.parseInt(integers);
```

Comment: Using a `try` and `catch` with `exception` is a bad way to control the flow of your program.  Using `Character.isDigit()` would be a much better way of determining if the character if a number.

Comment: Nice! Never knew that method existed. Updated.

Comment: The first method you had also worked, but I had to adapt it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Regex.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

---

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()){
    String number = matcher.group(1);
    String letters = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives me `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to call `matcher.find()`. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on the condition that the `date` argument is always a single `character` at the end of the `String`.

```
public static String[] splitDate(String date)
{
    int length = date.length();
    String[] results = {date.substring(0, length - 1), date.substring(length - 1)};
    return results;
}
```

Input of `110w` will return an array of `{110, w}`.

This method just uses `substring` based on the length of `String` and separates the number from the final character.